# Are wash sales calculated by my broker?

Tags: united-states, taxes, broker, wash-sale

For taxes, do I need to calculate wash sales myself, or are they typically reflected on the tax documents I will be sent by my broker?

Comment: How many brokers do you have? If you have more than one, they would not know what other investments you have.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for all brokers but my brokers provides an 8949 form which calculates wash sales (and is reported to the IRS).

I'd also add that they add a disclaimer that their form  is "not  intended to constitute tax advice which may be relied upon to avoid penalties under any federal, state, local or other tax statutes or regulations, and does not resolve any tax issues in your favor."

So keep an eye on your wash sales and your trading gains and losses.  I have found errors in broker prepared EOY tax forms.

Comment: if don't mind can you please name the broker

Comment: I have found an occasional error in my trading account at Interactive Brokers, sometimes in my favor, sometimes not.